# SQL Server select columnn as rows dynamically in resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Employee Monthly Attendance table as follows.

```
EmpID    EmpName Month  Year     Day1    Day2    Day3    Day4 .....   Day31

1        ABC      Dec   2014      P       A       WOF     PL           P
```

In above table P - Present, A - Absent, WOF - Weekly OFF, PL - Paid Leave

Now I have following query to display all the days in the particular month as follows

```
declare @StartDate DATE
declare @EndDate DATE
set @StartDate = '20141201'
set @EndDate = '20141231';

WITH DateRange AS
 (
     SELECT
         @StartDate Date1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
         DATEADD(day, 1, T0.Date1) Date
     FROM
         DateRange T0
     WHERE
         T0.Date1 < @EndDate
 )
```

Now I want result in following format

```
EmpId   EmpName   Date         Status

1       ABC       2014-12-01   P
1       ABC       2014-12-02   A
1       ABC       2014-12-03   WOF
1       ABC       2014-12-04   PL
.
.
.
.
.
.
1       ABC       2014-12-31   P
```

Please reply.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to achieve it with this part of code:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    empId int, EmpName nvarchar(50), month char(3), year int, 
    day1 varchar(5),day2 varchar(5),day3 varchar(5),day4 varchar(5),day5 varchar(5),day6 varchar(5),day7 varchar(5),
    day8 varchar(5),day9 varchar(5),day10 varchar(5),day11 varchar(5),day12 varchar(5),day13 varchar(5),day14 varchar(5),
    day15 varchar(5),day16 varchar(5),day17 varchar(5),day18 varchar(5),day19 varchar(5),day20 varchar(5),day21 varchar(5),
    day22 varchar(5),day23 varchar(5),day24 varchar(5),day25 varchar(5),day26 varchar(5),day27 varchar(5),day28 varchar(5),
    day29 varchar(5),day30 varchar(5),day31 varchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO #temp(empId, EmpName, month, year, 
    day1 ,day2 ,day3 ,day4 ,day5 ,day6 ,day7 ,
    day8 ,day9 ,day10 ,day11 ,day12 ,day13 ,day14 ,
    day15 ,day16 ,day17 ,day18 ,day19 ,day20 ,day21 ,
    day22 ,day23 ,day24 ,day25 ,day26 ,day27 ,day28 ,
    day29 ,day30 ,day31)
VALUES(1,N'Employee1',N'Dec',2014,
    N'A',N'B',N'C',N'D',N'E',N'F',N'G',
    N'A',N'B',N'C',N'D',N'E',N'F',N'G',
    N'A',N'B',N'C',N'D',N'E',N'F',N'G',
    N'A',N'B',N'C',N'D',N'E',N'F',N'G',
    N'X',N'Y',N'Z')

-- Your Part
SELECT unpvt.empId, unpvt.EmpName, 
    -- do the day trick
    CONVERT(date,
        CONVERT(nvarchar(max),unpvt.year)+N'-'
        +CONVERT(nvarchar(max),unpvt.month)+N'-'
        +REPLACE(unpvt.dayCol,N'Day',N'')
    ,106) as [Date], 
    value as [Status]
FROM #temp
UNPIVOT(
    value
    FOR dayCol IN([day1],[day2],[day3],[day4],[day5],[day6],[day7],
            [day8],[day9],[day10],[day11],[day12],[day13],[day14],
            [day15],[day16],[day17],[day18],[day19],[day20],[day21],
            [day22],[day23],[day24],[day25],[day26],[day27],[day28],
            [day29],[day30],[day31])
) as unpvt

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #temp
```

I'm using `UNPIVOT` to turn the columns into rows. After that I replace the columnname to get the day number and generate a `datetime` column from it.

But beside that this will solve your issue, the table design is really awful. Anyway, I'm sure that you haven't designed this and you just need to handle it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNPIVOT` like this.

**Query**

```
SELECT EmpID,EmpName,
CONVERT(DATE,REPLACE(Col,'Day','') + ' ' + [Month] + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[Year]),106) AttDate,
Val
FROM EmpATT
UNPIVOT(Val FOR Col IN([Day1], [Day2], [Day3], [Day4], [Day31])) as UPVT
```

**Output**

```
| EmpID | EmpName |    AttDate | Val |
|-------|---------|------------|-----|
|     1 |     ABC | 2014-12-01 |   P |
|     1 |     ABC | 2014-12-02 |   A |
|     1 |     ABC | 2014-12-03 | WOF |
|     1 |     ABC | 2014-12-04 |  PL |
|     1 |     ABC | 2014-12-31 |   P |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc40e/4)

Answer (score 0):

try this one in order to dynamically have the column set for days.

```
declare @columnName nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @ex nvarchar(max) = ''

select @columnName += quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ',' from (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'DateRange' and COLUMN_NAME like 'day%')


set @columnName = LEFT(@columnname,len(@columnname) - 1)


set @ex = '
select .... from DateRange
pivot ....
for ....
in (' + @columnName+ ')) as pivotT'

exec sp_executesql @ex
```